# Having trouble adding view created from a has_many: through table.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Hopefully I get all the terminology right here - if not please forgive, still very new.

I am working on a course project @Bloc and am having trouble with adding a list of collaborators to my index view for a different controller.

What I am trying to achieve is:
Show all user wikis - working.
Show all wikis where user is listed as a collaborator (link created through a join table and has_many through reference.)

My index view looks like: (/wikis/index)

```
<h1>My Wikis</h1>
 <% if policy(Wiki.new).create? %>
<%= link_to "New Wiki", new_wiki_path, class: 'btn btn-success' %>
<% end %>
<% @wikis.each do |wikis| %>
<div class="media">
 <div class="media-body">
   <h4 class="media-heading">
     <%= link_to wikis.title, wikis %>
   </h4>
  <small>
     Created <%= time_ago_in_words(wikis.created_at) %> ago by <%= wikis.user.name %><br/>
  </small>
 </div>
</div>

<% end %>

<h1>My Collaborations</h1>

<% @collaborations.each do |collaborations| %>
   <div class="media">
    <div class="media-body">
      <h4 class="media-heading">
        <%= link_to collaborations.title, collaborations %>
      </h4>

     </div>
   </div>

<% end %>


<%= will_paginate @wikis %>
```

My Wikis controller looks like: (shortened)

```
class WikisController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :js

  def index
    # @user = current_user

    @wikis = current_user.wikis.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10)
    #@collaboration = @wiki.collaboration.build(collaboration_params)
    @collaborations = @collaboration.where(:user_id == current_user)
    authorize @wikis
  end

  def show
    @wikis = Wiki.friendly.find(params[:id])
    if request.path != wiki_path(@wikis)
      redirect_to @wikis, status: :moved_permanently
      authorize @wikis
    end
  end
end

  private
  def collaboration_params
    params.require(:collaboration).permit(:user_id, :wiki_id)
  end

end
```

From the Rails Console - I can see that my collaboration relationship is working as expected - I just cannot quite figure out what the syntax is I should be using to make it render on my index view.

```
2.0.0-p481 :022 > Collaboration.last
  Collaboration Load (1.9ms)  SELECT  "collaborations".* FROM "collaborations"   ORDER BY    "collaborations"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
log writing failed. Protocol error - /home/vagrant/code/blocipedia/log/development.log
 => #<Collaboration id: 3, user_id: 1, wiki_id: 16>
2.0.0-p481 :023 >
```

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated. I've tried what feels like about 100 different combinations to figure this out.

Right now the error I trigger on index view is:

```
undefined method `where' for nil:NilClass
```

Cheers
Kevin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Object**

The simple error you have is here:

```
@collaborations = @collaboration.where(:user_id == current_user)
```

The error here is that you're calling `.where` on a variable which has not been populated (defined).

Ruby / Rails works somewhat differently to other languages, in that it's [*object orientated*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming). This means that each time Rails calls an "object", it will actually be *defined*, just not *populated*.

As a rule of thumb, the `no method error` is generally (although not always) a result of the system having not populated the variable correctly.

---

**Model**

The way to fix this is very simple -

You just need to be able to declare the `@collaboration` object *before* calling the `.where` method: on it. However, as you're using the `.build` method to define this object, you're not going to get anywhere.

Essentially, when you perform a `.where` lookup, you'll be using ActiveRecord to ping the datatables in the backend, populating an `object` with the various attributes from the Model (look up [MVC programming pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) for more about this)

What you need to do (if you want to call `.where`) is *create an instance* of the model you wish to query inside the database. To do this, you either have to call the model directly, or through an associative object:

```
def index
    @wikis = current_user.wikis.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10)
    @collaborations = Collaboration.where(user_id: current_user.id)
    authorize @wikis
end
```

---

**System**

As you're new to Rails, let me give you some details on how to make the *system* work properly.

Firstly, you need to appreciate the role of [ActiveRecord Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) - these are built on the [ActiveRecord pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record_pattern), making it much simpler to build "objects" around database-driven data

In short, if you *associate* two or more objects with ActiveRecord, it means you can call the *associative* data through the primary object:

```
#app/models/user.rb
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :collaborations
end

#app/models/collaboration.rb
Class Collaboration < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
end
```

[image]

This means that instead of calling `@collaborations = Collaboration.where(user_id: current_user.id), you'll simply be able to call`@collaborations = current_user.collaborations`

---

**Fix**

The fix should be as follows:

```
#app/views/wiki/index.html.erb
...
<% current_user.collaborations.each do |collaboration| %>
   <div class="media">
    <div class="media-body">
      <h4 class="media-heading">
        <%= link_to collaboration.title, collaboration %>
      </h4>
     </div>
   </div>
<% end %>

#app/controllers/wikis_controller.rb
Class WikisController < ApplicationController
   def index
    @wikis = current_user.wikis.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10)
    authorize @wikis
   end
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Rich - I was able to get it working by going through and following your answer. I did have to deviate a little as I had referred to collaborated_wikis but once that was fixed everything worked great!

Comment: Nice! Glad you got it working!! Thanks for the reply :)